# Issue with pytorch LSTM source code

Tags: python, deep-learning, lstm, pytorch

I am using bidirectional LSTM with `batch_first=True`. However, it is throwing me an error regarding dimensions.

`**Error:
Expected hidden[0] size (6, 5, 40), got (5, 6, 40)**`

When I checked the source code, the error occurred due to below function

```
if is_input_packed:
            mini_batch = int(batch_sizes[0])
        else:
            mini_batch = input.size(0) if self.batch_first else input.size(1)

        num_directions = 2 if self.bidirectional else 1
        expected_hidden_size = (self.num_layers * num_directions,
                                mini_batch, self.hidden_size)

        def check_hidden_size(hx, expected_hidden_size, msg='Expected hidden size {}, got {}'):
            if tuple(hx.size()) != expected_hidden_size:
                raise RuntimeError(msg.format(expected_hidden_size, tuple(hx.size())))
```

By default `expected_hidden_size` is written with respect to sequence first. I believe it is causing the problem. Can someone advise if I am right and the issue needs to be fixed?

Comment: Can you also add the code where you get the error?